# Can the booted kernel version differ from the version against which a module has been built?

Tags: module, linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to build and install kernel modules for a network card, from source. The module sources seem very picky in terms of which kernel version they can compile against.

I have managed to build the modules against the LTS kernel headers for my distribution, Arch Linux, which at the moment are `linux-lts-headers 5.10.37-1`. Does this mean that I need to actually install and boot this exact same kernel version, to use the modules? Or do the modules have some tolerance between the booted version and the version they were compiled against?

I realise this is dependent on what exactly I'm building but I'm interested in common practice, do's and don'ts. For example, for a rolling release distro it would be a lot of work to rebuild the module with every minor mainline kernel update, for example right now `linux-headers 5.12.3` -> `linux-headers 5.12.4`. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: you can try modprobe module  --force-vermagic but kernel should be build with CONFIG_MODULE_FORCE_LOAD

Comment: Thanks both. So do I understand correctly that this will be hit-and-miss. A better bet is to boot from the LTS kernel.

@Varun I don't know if stock kernel packages have that option

Comment: To be more precise - if my module didn't *compile* with some kernel, it would be naive, as a workaround, to compile against a slightly different version and force-loading it into the version that didn't compile, correct?

Comment: Yes .. your are correct on this.. It will be always be risky with different kernel and module version

Comment: Rebuilding external modules when the kernel is updated can be automated using DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support). It should be in your distro's repo.

Comment: @IanAbbott ok, but these DKMS packages seem to be in rpm format, which my distro doesn't use. Is this the norm? I've got one with the extension "noarch.rpm"

Comment: Doesn't your distro offer its own dkms package? Most do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you usually never find prebuilt kernel module distributed somewhere. You have to build kernel module with kernel headers of your running kernel. Common practice is always having the right kernel headers in your `/usr/src`